# useEffect issue on refresh undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

When i refresh the page i get cannot read property as undefined, however it's only when i refresh the page. I'm just windering what i need to do here to fix the issue?

```
import Header from "../components/Header.js";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.js";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import Image from "next/image";
import { db } from "../firebase.js";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import React, { useHook, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function View() {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;
    const[result, setResults] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('results').doc(id).get()
        .then(snapshot => setResults(snapshot.data()))
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />

                <main className="pb-14">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <section className="flex-grow pt-10 pb-7 px-6">
                            <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-6">
                                { result.title }
                            </h1>
                        </section>
                    </div>>
                </main>

            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default View
```

Comment: Which property is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, your problem has nothing to do with the `useEffect`. You just need to check the `result` on the loading stage.

You're trying to access `result.title`, but the result value is `undefined`, so it becomes `undefined.title`, which is incorrect.

Try this:

```js
import Header from "../components/Header.js";
import Footer from "../components/Footer.js";
import Loading from "../components/Loading.js";
import { useRouter } from "next/dist/client/router";
import { format } from "date-fns";
import Image from "next/image";
import { db } from "../firebase.js";
import firebase from 'firebase';
import React, { useHook, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function View() {

    const router = useRouter();
    const { id } = router.query;
    const[result, setResults] = useState(undefined);

    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('results').doc(id).get()
        .then(snapshot => setResults(snapshot.data()))
    }, []);

    if (typeof result === 'undefined'){
      return <Loading />
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <Header />

                <main className="pb-14">
                    <div className="flex">
                        <section className="flex-grow pt-10 pb-7 px-6">
                            <h1 className="text-3xl font-semibold mt-2 mb-6">
                                { result.title }
                            </h1>
                        </section>
                    </div>>
                </main>

            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

export default View
```

PS: Also, you can have a boolean state for the loading stage

Comment: This does not work and show the result at loading, it just shows a potential loader on refresh

Comment: @BrianMillot your document at `/results/{id}` doesn't exist which means that `snapshot.data()` is `undefined`. Which causes Alireza's answer to forever show the `Loading` component. You need to handle the case where `/results/{id}` doesn't exist gracefully.

Comment: Thanks sam, but the id exist since it comes from the router,, my url looks the same on refresh. http://localhost:3000/view?id=YoNU3fP3xEY9XHv3gKT5 That's why i'm confused